# LED control using GPIO

Tags: led, transistors, control, gpio

I am using an industrial camera that has GPIO ports which I would like to use for turning LED plate off and on. LED runs on 24 V and 350 mA (between 350 mA and 1500 mA but 350 mA would be optimal).

GPIO output (TTL) parameters are: 
Level low: 0-0.8 V
Level high: 2.4-3.0 V
Current: 0-4 mA.

Is there an off the shelf solution for this problem since company would like to have already existing solution without worrying about producing this component?

Comment: ...a transistor? Did you do any research? Sounds more like company has no electrical engineering talent at all, and would prefer to outsource work to stackexchange for free.

Comment: The answer is 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "off the shelf" solution would be an opto-isolated solid state relay rated for DC loads.

With more care to safe application, a lower cost solution using an NPN power transistor in the negative-side supply to the LED and a series resistor between the base and the driving GPIO can be designed.  An N-channel MOSFET would also be an option, but at increase in the number of potential design (and handling) issues.